# Field type in mySQL

Tags: mysql

It's a quick question, but I can't seem to be able to find the right answer...
I need to store numeric values in mySQL table. Some can be positive, some negative.
The largest can be 100 the smallest -100. What is the best data type I should use? VARCHAR? INT works only with positives, right?

Comment: `VARCHAR` is for text data, `INT` *can* work for negatives too if it's not `UNSIGNED`.

Answer (score 2):

`INT` types work for both positive and negative.

You can use the `TINYINT SIGNED` to store integer values between `-128` and `+127`.

If you want to store not only integers but numbers with fractional parts, you can use either `FLOAT` or `DECIMAL(m.n)`. With `DECIMAL(5,2)` you could store any value from `-999.99` to `+999.99` (5 digits, 2 after the decimal point).

Answer (score 1):

You want to use TINYINT http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

Answer (score 1):

Use a `tinyint`

http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/integer-types.html

Answer (score 0):

INT works with negative numbers as well as long as you don't specify UNSIGNED. TINYINT (-128 to 127) would be the best choice for your range of values.

Comment: Smallint is -32768 to 32767, TINYINT would be better as it's -128 to 127